# How much can sitemaps be nested inside sitemaps?

Tags: sitemap

Take Grammarly, for example:
https://www.grammarly.com/sitemap.xml

A smaller website would just have that sitemap.xml list all the actual URLs, but Grammarly has that sitemap list two (sub) sitemaps. If I go into those (sub) sitemaps, then they do actually list the URLs.

However, can this be nested further? That'd mean a (sub) sitemap links to other (sub) (sub) sitemaps, and recursively so on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submission of nested sitemaps and nesting levels](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84047/submission-of-nested-sitemaps-and-nesting-levels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are sitemap index files and sitemap files. The [sitemap protocol](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) specifies that a sitemap index file can contain up to 50,000 sitemap files and must be no larger than 50MB. Each sitemap file can contain up to 50,000 URLs and also must be no larger than 50MB.

Besides listing sitemap files within sitemap index files no nesting is allowed. Sitemap index files are not allowed to contain other sitemap index files and sitemap files are not allowed to contain other sitemap files. However you can have multiple sitemap index files if needed:

```
/
├── sitemap-index-1.xml
│   ├── sitemap-1.xml
│   │   ├── url-1
│   │   ├── url-2
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── url-50000
│   ├── sitemap-2.xml
│   │   ├── url-1
│   │   ├── url-2
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── url-50000 
│   ├──  ...
│   └── sitemap-50000.xml
│       ├── url-1
│       ├── url-2
│       ├── ...
│       └── url-50000 
├── sitemap-index-2.xml
│   ├── sitemap-1.xml
│   │   ├── url-1
│   │   ├── url-2
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── url-50000
│   ├── sitemap-2.xml
│   │   ├── url-1
│   │   ├── url-2
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── url-50000 
│   ├──  ...
│   └── sitemap-50000.xml
│       ├── url-1
│       ├── url-2
│       ├── ...
│       └── url-50000 
├── ...
├── sitemap-index-N.xml
│   ├── sitemap-1.xml
│   │   ├── url-1
│   │   ├── url-2
│   │   ├── ...
...
```